# Get invoice total from a collection with arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with this structure:

```
db.shops.insert({
  "customer": "21c3",
  "shopDate": new Date("2019-06-03T23:00:00Z"),
  "shopId" : "Supermarket",
  "items" : [
    {
      "productName": "Water",
      "price": 3,
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "productName": "Candies",
      "price": 1,
      "quantity": 5
    }
  ]
});
```

I need a query to get the total amount of each shopId.

This is what I have done, but it is not working:

```
db.shops.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : $shopName,
          totalSold: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } },
        }
      }
   ]
);
```

Comment: This should be the best one https://mongoplayground.net/p/vQtEEp65dQn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
db.shops.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$unwind": "$items"
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                _id : "$shopId",
                totalSold: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$items.price", "$items.quantity" ] } },
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: You could also add a projection at the start if it is a lot of shops to reduce the load: { $project: {'_id': 0, 'shopId': 1, 'items.price': 1, 'items.quantity': 1} }